# Snapshot key not working with value findindex?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

How to make work findIndex depending of a snapshotkey ?it's not working with the variable but actually work with a manual string ?!

```
 this.state.data =     Object {

  "date_add": 1574177488383,
  "date_upd": 1574178141010,
  "question": "1",
"key": "123455566",
}
ref.on('child_changed', snapshot => {
          var key = snapshot.key


          console.log('the key', key) // return 123455566
})
```

actually not working like this :

```
      var foundIndex = this.state.data.findIndex(x => x.key == key);
```

but work like this

```
 var foundIndex = this.state.data.findIndex(x => x.key == '123455566');
```

Comment: can you please add complete code here ?

Comment: what code you need ? it's a simple findindex who work with string but not with an object what can i add ?

Comment: how to i convert my object into value ??

Answer (score 0):

```
var key = "123456";
var data = [{"key":"123456"},{"key": "123"},{"key":  "12"}, {"key":"1"}]
var foundIndex = data.findIndex(x => x.key == key);
console.log(foundIndex); //0
var ind = data.findIndex(x => x.key == '12'); 
console.log(ind); //2
```

Comment: it's already work when i write it as string but not when i use a KEY from an object

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
var foundIndex = this.state.data.findIndex(x => x.key == x.key);
```

Im not sure what you are trying to get but, you use`findindex` to get the index of a value.

You can see multiple examples here:

[Get the index of the object inside an array, matching a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997879/get-the-index-of-the-object-inside-an-array-matching-a-condition)

[Find index of object in javascript by a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49574994/find-index-of-object-in-javascript-by-a-value)

Also the docs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

Comment: what ? i try to get by specific key it's working when i write it but not from object ?

Comment: Did you enter any of these links?

Comment: yes and you dont understand i try to get the index of the value depending of my key ? why do you use x.key == x.key ? where is the specific variable key here ?

Comment: I thought key is the whole object

Comment: Inside `child_changed` add `console.log(this.state.data.findIndex(x => x.key == key));` because if you are using it outside `child_changed` then `key` would be null because it is asychronous

Comment: it is inside actually , the fact it's working well with i write the manual return of my variable ! but not directly with it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202661/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-manyouuwx).

Comment: Did you try the answer?